# action bar is going behind the status bar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-actionbar, android-statusbar

my action bar is going behind the staus bar. and when i click on any buttion on the action bar it comes below the staus bar perfectly. 
here is a pic of how the action bar is going behind the action bar :

[image: screenshot]

here is my xml code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:background="@mipmap/background"
    tools:context="com.creaa.admin.solvist.ProfileActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#20000000"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="#20000000"
            android:title=""
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="MY PROFILE"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
         </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_profile" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

here is the style file :

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>

    </style>
    <style name="SplashScreen">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>

    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

java code :

```
public class ProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
ActionBar actionBar;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setTitle("");
         DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.profile, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.creaa.admin.solvist">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".LandingPageActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:theme="@style/SplashScreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ProfileActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: hide the states bar..

Comment: post the style file @Parth

Comment: i want the status bar

Comment: ok first let post the style file.. style file contain the property which set actionbar behind status bar

Comment: @AngadTiwari added the style file. please help me

Comment: @ParthAnjaria .. attach MyProfile Java File as well as AndroidManifest.xml... from here, i found nothing

Comment: just add `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` to your `CoordinatorLayout` in XML.

Comment: but now my layout is going behind the below navigation bar

Answer (score 4):

Add

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

to your CoordinatorLayout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
 android:background="@mipmap/background"
 tools:context="com.creaa.admin.solvist.ProfileActivity">
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use check in your activity or baseActivity oncreate

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
        //then set status bar color or any thing else
    }
```